# Bash script failing with unknown option due to space in argument

Tags: shell-script, shell, quoting

I am trying to run aws create lambda function. It goes as follows -

```
eval $(aws lambda create-function \
--function-name $FUNCTION_NAME \
--runtime $RUNTIME \
--role $ROLE \
--handler $HANDLER \
--region $REGION \
--zip-file $ZIP_FILE \
--profile $PROFILE \
--environment $env_variables)
```

All the variables come from command line. It is failing for env_variables. This gets constructed as -

```
env_variables="Variables={INPUT=${DAYS}}"
```

where DAYS is actually `"20 days"`

How can I avoid this space and pass my command successfully.

Comment: Did you try proper quoting?

Comment: I need a string like `env_variables="Variables={INPUT=20 days}"` which means `"Variables={INPUT=20 days}"` is a json sting fed to environment option of the command. I tried DAYS="\'45 days\'". Does not work.

Comment: Please put that update ^^ ^^ ^^ into your question, where it belongs so that everyone can easily find it.

Comment: I guess it was quotes after all.  Took couple of hour to figure correct combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Finally following worked -

```
env_variables="\"Variables\":{\"INPUT\":\"${DAYS}\"}"

lambda_create_command="aws lambda create-function --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --runtime $RUNTIME --role $ROLE --handler $HANDLER --region $REGION --zip-file $ZIP_FILE --profile $PROFILE --environment '$env_variables'"

echo "Executing command : $lambda_create_command"

eval $lambda_create_command
```

Important points -

1. Quotes in `env_variables`
2. Use of `eval`
3. Single quote in command string i.e `$env_variables`

Reference - https://gist.github.com/andywirv/f312d561c9702522f6d4ede1fe2750bd